# How to make an array of a composed type in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

I was trying

```
class Output
  alias Type = String | Array(Output) | Hash(Symbol, Output)
  
  getter raw

  def initialize(@raw : Type)
  end
end

hash = Output.new({ :a => Output.new("1") })
array = Output.new([hash.raw])
```

Answer (score 1):

`Type` includes `Array(Output)` so I needed to pass the output and not the raw type:

```
array = Output.new([hash])
```